# Insert xlsx file in Excel with javascript (Office Add-in)

Tags: javascript, excel, base64, ms-office, xlsx

How do I insert and xlsx file on an Excel worksheet? Like you insert in Word with Document.body.insertFilefromBase64 or Ooxml or Html.

Excel does not have an insert method in Worksheet or Workbook. [Documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet)